# Build XML for soap request

Tags: php, xml, soap

How would you build a soap request manually? I didn't bother looking for a soap client for php so I am trying to build the requests manually. Here is a sample of the request:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <EWalletLoginCmd xmlns="xxxxxxx">
      <ewalleTID>string</ewalleTID>
      <PIN>string</PIN>
    </EWalletLoginCmd>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I made a function for sending the request like:

```
private function send($url, $xml) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $xml));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

But I am lost on how to actually build the XML, I started with:

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

    $body = $xml->createElement('body');
    $xml->appendChild($body);

    return $xml->saveXML();
```

But how do you specifiy `<soap12:`? I am new to soap and xml on php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has the [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) class built in for using SOAP. 
if your SOAP server has a wsdl try

```
$wsdl= 'location of your servers wsdl';
$options = array('soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 'trace'=>true);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```

then you can call any method on your client like

```
$results = $client->EWalletLoginCmd(array('ewalleTID'=>'...', 'PIN'=>'...'));
```

Comment: the api is telling me to send post requests to a `.asmx` path.

Comment: try adding ?WSDL to the end of the path

Comment: Checking that replied something like `<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/`